# Attempting to delete an image from Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I'm going nuts trying to do something very simple. I have a number of images in my app that are displayed at certain times. In the course of playing around with retina images, I delete the image files from my app. Except that when I ran the app in the Simulator, the images are still there. I checked the project folder in Finder, and the images are definitely gone. I've cleaned and rebuilt the app, but they're still displaying. If I build the app for the iPhone, they're not displayed. So how do I clean it up for the Simulator?

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just deleting it from the simulator as you would on a normal iPhone, then running from XCode. If that doesn't work, quit the simluator and go to ${HOME}/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/${OS_VERSION}/Applications. There will be folders for each application named after the application's id. Find the folder for your application and delete it. Then run again from XCode.