# Images staying behind in Xcode or Phonegap?

Tags: xcode, image, cordova, zepto

So, I am having a really strange error in my app right now. I'm using Zepto and Phonegap. I have a target that moves around the screen, and used to load it from an image. Now, I'm using css to draw it. However, even though I removed all copies of the image, and even the image and div tags in the HTML file, the image sticks around. I have no idea what's causing it, I've restarted several times, and cleaned it several more. Does anyone know what may be causing this?

EDIT: Somehow, I fixed it. I don't know what I did, or why it worked, but it did. I think. Anyways, I'd still like to hear if anyone has had this happen before, and why it does.

Comment: cmd+shift+k to clean the project. You need to do this every time you deploy to simulator or device. HTML gets cached heavily http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673691/clear-phonegap-cache/8674319#8674319

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this happens in xcode because of caching..

[Here is someone with the same issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560568/xcode-cant-remove-launch-image-from-project)

> iPhone Simulator caches stuff. Try a clean build, or actually deleting the app from the simulator (by holding down on a home screen icon until it wiggles, then X-ing it).

Comment: That didn't work when I tried it, and I tried it several times. I ended up doing something with the CSS files, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: This is a common problem though, and you should have done more searching. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649704/attempting-to-delete-an-image-from-xcode-4

Comment: And I tried that solution, but it didn't work. I don't know what I did to fix it, though.