# Xcode -- delete images are still getting built when building app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, ios5

I am trying to clean up my app before I submit it for apple approval, but I have an issue. I have delete some unwanted background images but the app seems to think they are still there. I have delete the app completely from the phone but when I build it is still there. The image has been completely remove from the Mac it doesn't exist anywhere not even in the simulator folder

```
/Users/******/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/*********/appname.app
```

I can't seem to figure out whats going wrong.

I have had a look at a few questions like

[Xcode- Deleted images appear in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821316/xcode-deleted-images-appear-in-simulator)

but this doesn't work, I have also tried

[Attempting to delete an image from Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649704/attempting-to-delete-an-image-from-xcode-4)

when it builds it just adds it back in.

Can anyone help? or advice where I can find some help?

Comment: Delete it and then, from Xcode, perform that:
1. Press Shift+Cmd+K
2. Press Alt+Shift+Cmd+K

Comment: I have deleted it from xcode, I have deleted it from the simulator path provided, I just doesn't exist anywhere its like its getting cached somewhere.

Comment: @MarcoPace if you can please add your comment as an answer I will accept it as this works for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Delete it and then, from Xcode, perform that:

1. Press Shift+Cmd+K
2. Alt+Shift+Cmd+K

It will empty your cache and clean your build folder.

Comment: In addition to this, you need to delete the app from the simulator.

Answer (score 3):

Product -> Clean or ⌘-Shift-K.

Answer (score 2):

In the project tree click the name of the project name, select targets and build phases tab. There will be a section named "copy bundle resources", if you can see the name of your file, delete it from there. Then follow others' solution to clear the cache and make a clean build.

Edit: Also check [Xcode- Deleted images appear in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821316/xcode-deleted-images-appear-in-simulator), I guess your question is answered there.

Comment: This worked for me, deleting them from the "Copy Bundle Resources" file.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning your project and then building it again ? (It might still used the already built .app file when you uploaded it again to your phone)

Comment: I thought I had but can you just as instruction on a clean build?

Answer (score 0):

i think thats happens because of you are deleting the reference of images so that images are still in the folder of your project so do these 3 things.
1. go to your project folder where it is saved and search those images and if you found those images in that folder than delete them.
2. clean your project. from product->clean
3. delete app from simulator
after that try again i think your problem is resolved.