# Image not visible on Device but appers on the simulator

Tags: objective-c

In my app I have set custom image for segment control. Image shows up very well on the simulator but not on the device. I checked all possible ways and tried what ever was answered for this issue earlier for the issues same as I have now. But still I can't locate exact solution for this. Can anyone help please.

Comment: Thanks you so much for trying to help me. But I have already found solution for my issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try removing/readding the image? As far as I know, the simulator has its own cache, if the image has been removed somehow, that may be why its showing up.

You may try:

1. Remove the image from xcode, and re-adding it
2. Making a clean build
3. Remove the image from "bundle resources", (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12741872/936957) and readding it
4. Quitting / restarting xcode

One of them should help

Comment: This helped me to fix the problem. Thank you so much for your help.